# Firefox not loading all objects

Tags: asp.net, firefox, firefox-addon

I've a report which has five pages(graphs) that is called through firefox to send mails to the respective users.The scripting was done in .net(and I'm a novice at it).

The process used to work fine until a few days,but since the past few days the process has been failing to send the mail as firefox is just loading only 2 pages(graphs) and exiting after that.

It sends mail when we manually drag the scrollbar to load all five pages.

What could be the reason that's stopping it from loading all the five images(graphs).

We've removed all add-ons except shock wave flash plugin which is required for the report.

Thanks a lot!

```
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count)
                        {

                            Process p = Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe", "http://172.18.12.13/charts/dailyreport.aspx?ceid=" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["loginid"].ToString() + "&cename=" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["loginname"].ToString() + "&email=" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["emailid"].ToString());
                            Thread.Sleep(timeinterval);
                            if (!p.HasExited)
                                p.Kill();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        //    Process p = Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe", "http://172.18.12.13/charts/CustomReports.aspx");
                        //    Thread.Sleep(timeinterval);
                        //    if (!p.HasExited)
                        //        p.Kill();
                            Process global = Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe", "http://172.18.12.13/charts/Report_Global.aspx");
                            Thread.Sleep(timeinterval);
                            if (!global.HasExited)
                                global.Kill();
                        }
```

Comment: would you please add the relevant Code and try Debugging so you may find the problem youreself

Comment: I hope the problem's not with code but with firefox...any new update in the latest version that could be stopping it from loading all images....

Comment: We would have to see the code that you wrote so we see with what in Firefox it interacts with. Otherwise there's no hope to help you out.

Comment: @VJAI it doesnt matter if the Problem is within your code or with Firefox. We have to see the code, else we cant analyze/debug.

Comment: Donno if this is what you're asking for ...but found this out in the solution..Added the code above

Comment: Yes that's what we were looking for. Very interesting. Ok can you give us a live working example of a page `http://172.18.12.13/charts/dailyreport.aspx?ceid=" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["loginid"].ToString() + "&cename=" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["loginname"].ToString() + "&email=" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["emailid"].ToString()`. So please share with us this url but with actual values that work. So we can load the page ourselves and test.

Comment: Sorry Notidart...I ain't a .net developer. hence checked with them and can't share them with you...(Organization Policies are gonna get after me :-() but I hope it's the problem with flash player...is there a way you can help me get with this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I achieved by using a scrollbar function written in aspx.Below is the code,just in case anyone faces a similar situation.

```
`function ScrollDown() {
                   window.scrollBy(0, 50);
                   scrolldelay = setTimeout('ScrollDown()', 100);

<body onload="ScrollDown()">
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
        <asp:Literal ID ="chart1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        <asp:Literal ID ="chart2" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        <asp:Literal ID ="chart3" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        <asp:Literal ID ="chart4" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        <asp:Literal ID ="chart5" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>`
```